# Align two tables

Tags: css

**Problem:** I am able to align two tables side by side.

The issue that I am having is when I try to print the two tables, the second table appears on the second page rather along side with the table before it.

I did the following:

```css
.table2 {
  float: left;
  background: yellow;
}

.table1 {
  float: left;
  background: green;
}

.blah {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  font-family: century gothic !important;
  font-size: 12pt !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 80px;
}

.blah2 {
  font-family: century gothic !important;
  font-size: 11pt !important;
}

.blah3 {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  font-family: times !important;
  font-size: 11pt !important;
}

.blah4 {
  font-family: century gothic !important;
  font-size: 11pt !important;
}

.blah5 {
  font-family: century gothic !important;
  font-size: 11pt !important;
}

.blah6 {
  font-family: century gothic !important;
  font-size: 8pt !important;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center"><img src="image.png" /></div>
<div class="blah">Notice Informing Individuals about Nondiscrimination<br /> and Accessibility Requirements</div>
<div class="blah2">
  <div style="padding-bottom: 8px; font-weight: bold">Discrimination is against the law</div>
  <div style="padding-bottom: 15px; width: 92%">Blue Shield of California complies with applicable federal civil rights laws and does not discriminate on the basis of race, color, national origin, age, disability or sex. Blue Shield of California does not exclude people or treat them differently
    because of race, color, national origin, age, disability or sex.</div>Blue Shield of California:
  <div class="blah3">
    <table class="table2" width="90%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="blah4">• Provides aids and services at no cost to people with disabilities to communicate <br /> &nbsp;&nbsp; effectively with us such as:
            <div class="blah4">-&nbsp;&nbsp; Qualified sign language interpreters</div>
            <div class="blah4">-&nbsp;&nbsp; Written information in other formats (including large print, audio, accessible <br /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; electronic&nbsp;formats and other formats)</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="blah4">• Provides language services at no cost to people whose primary language is not English<br /> &nbsp;&nbsp; such as
            <div class="blah4">-&nbsp;&nbsp; Qualified interpreters</div>
            <div class="blah4">-&nbsp;&nbsp; Information written in other languages</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" style="width: 95%;" class="blah5">If you need these services, contact the Blue Shield of California Civil Rights Coordinator.<br />
            <br /> If you believe that Blue Shield of California has failed to provide these services or discriminated in another way on the basis of race, color, national origin, age, disability, or sex, you can file a grievance with:<br />
            <br />
            <div class="blah5">Blue Shield of California <br /> Civil Rights Coordinator<br /> P.O. Box 629007<br /> El Dorado Hills, CA 95762-9007</div>
            <div style="margin-top: 5px; font-weight: bold" class="blah5">Phone: (844) 831-4133 (TTY: 711)<br /> Fax: (916) 350-7405<br /> Email: BlueShieldCivilRightsCoordinator@blueshieldca.com</div><br />
            <div style="padding-bottom: 12px;" class="blah5">You can file a grievance in person or by mail, fax, or email. If you need help filing a grievance, our Civil Rights Coordinator is available to help you.</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="table1">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="image.png" /></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table width="95%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="blah6">Blue Shield of California</span><br />
            <span class="blah6">50 Beale Street, San Francisco, CA 94105</span></td>
          <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: bottom"><span style="font-family: century gothic !important; font-size: 8pt !important">blueshieldca.com</span></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also tried the following. Again, it shows the image alongside along with the text. However, when I try to print it out, it forces the image to jump to the second page:

```css
.blah {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  font-family: century gothic !important;
  font-size: 12pt !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 80px;
}

.blah2 {
  font-family: century gothic !important;
  font-size: 11pt !important;
}

.blah3 {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  font-family: times !important;
  font-size: 11pt !important;
}

.blah4 {
  font-family: century gothic !important;
  font-size: 11pt !important;
}

.blah5 {
  font-family: century gothic !important;
  font-size: 11pt !important;
}

.blah6 {
  font-family: century gothic !important;
  font-size: 8pt !important;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center"><img src="image.png" /></div>
<div class="blah">Notice Informing Individuals about Nondiscrimination<br /> and Accessibility Requirements</div>
<div class="blah2">
  <div clas="blah2" style="padding-bottom: 8px; font-weight: bold">Discrimination is against the law</div>
  <div style="padding-bottom: 15px; width: 92%">Blue Shield of California complies with applicable federal civil rights laws and does not discriminate on the basis of race, color, national origin, age, disability or sex. Blue Shield of California does not exclude people or treat them differently
    because of race, color, national origin, age, disability or sex.</div>Blue Shield of California:
  <div class="blah2">
    <table width="99%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" sclass="blah2">&bull; Provides aids and services at no cost to people with disabilities to communicate <br /> &nbsp;&nbsp; effectively with us such as:
            <div class="blah2">-&nbsp;&nbsp; Qualified sign language interpreters</div>
            <div class="blah2">-&nbsp;&nbsp; Written information in other formats (including large print, audio, accessible <br /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; electronic&nbsp;formats and other formats)</div>
          </td>
          <td rowspan="4" style="text-align: right; vertical-align: bottom"><img src="image.png" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="blah2">&bull; Provides language services at no cost to people whose primary language is not English<br /> &nbsp;&nbsp; such as
            <div stclass="blah2">-&nbsp;&nbsp; Qualified interpreters</div>
            <div class="blah2">-&nbsp;&nbsp; Information written in other languages</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" style="width: 95%;" class="blah2"><br /> If you need these services, contact the Blue Shield of California Civil Rights Coordinator.<br />
            <br /> If you believe that Blue Shield of California has failed to provide these services or discriminated in another way on the basis of race, color, national origin, age, disability, or sex, you can file a grievance with:<br />
            <br />
            <div class="blah2">Blue Shield of California <br /> Civil Rights Coordinator<br /> P.O. Box 629007<br /> El Dorado Hills, CA 95762-9007</div>
            <div style="margin-top: 5px; font-weight: bold" class="blah2">Phone: (844) 831-4133 (TTY: 711)<br /> Fax: (916) 350-7405<br /> Email: BlueShieldCivilRightsCoordinator@blueshieldca.com</div><br />
            <div style="padding-bottom: 12px;" class="blah2">You can file a grievance in person or by mail, fax, or email. If you need help filing a grievance, our Civil Rights Coordinator is available to help you.</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table width="95%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="blah6" style="font-weight:bold">Blue Shield of California</span><br />
            <span class="blah6">50 Beale Street, San Francisco, CA 94105</span></td>
          <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: bottom"><span class="blah6">blueshieldca.com</span></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

How would I achieve showing what is shown on the screen, meaning the two tables side by side vs have the second table being pushed to the second page?

Comment: Firstly... Clean your code... Use indents (TAB vs Spaces), separate element from Text Everything is inline and a mess...

Comment: OMG, this inline style made me blind

Comment: Im dying laughing right now!! Roberto, please use just an example... Base frame only..

Comment: @Everyone: Changes have been made

Comment: @Cam changes have been made

Comment: @AlonEitan Changes have been made

Comment: @RobertoFlores what did you change mate?

Comment: @yarwest readable.

Comment: @RobertoFlores I can see you did an attempt to improve, but it really didn't get more understandable

Comment: @yarwest I will make it understandable shortly

Comment: @RobertoFlores I gave you a plus 1 for dealing with this and not getting salty and deleting your question!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution.  Nest your 2 tables into a table.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            TABLE 2
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            TABLE 1
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```